# Create an array of objects with specific types and keys from original array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, key, destructuring

I have an array ob object

```js
const myDailyRutine= [
      {
        createdLetter:
        date: "2018-10-12T05:44:44.553216+00:00"
        user: {username: "lady-gaga"}
      }, 
      {
        commentedEmail:
        date: "2018-10-12T05:44:44.553216+00:00"
        user: {username: "la-gaga", display_name: "La Gaga"}
      },
      {
      commentedEmail:
      date: "2018-10-12T05:44:44.553216+00:00"
       user: {username: "maira-ter", display_name: "Ma Ter"}
      }
  ];
```

I want to map over the array of objects and add a key 'type' to each event to identify what type of event it is 'createdEmail || createdLetter`

I tried a couple of things such as pick from lodash but I'm not getting the results I want.

How may I achieve this?

Comment: What are the values for fields `createdLetter` or `commentedEmail` - currently `myDailyRutine` has invalid syntax

Comment: inside of each of those you find date and user

Comment: What I would like to be able to create is an array on objects that have a type key that tell me what type of activity it was.  for example const newArray = [{type: createdEmail: {all other fields}}, {type: createdLetter: {all other fields}]; I want to be able to differentiate what type of activity it is.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try firs first iteration - `map` method will detect if object has only one property and assign it to new created `type` property:

```js
const myDailyRutine = [{
    createdLetter: {
      date: "2018-10-12T05:44:44.553216+00:00",
      user: {
        username: "lady-gaga"
      },
    },
  },
  {
    commentedEmail: {
      date: "2018-10-12T05:44:44.553216+00:00",
      user: {
        username: "la-gaga",
        display_name: "La Gaga"
      },
    },
  },
  {
    commentedEmail: {
      date: "2018-10-12T05:44:44.553216+00:00",
      user: {
        username: "maira-ter",
        display_name: "Ma Ter"
      },
    },
  },
]

const getValueOfFirstProperty = obj => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)
  if (keys.lenght > 1) throw new RangeError("Expected only one keys")
  return keys[0]
}

console.log(
  myDailyRutine.map(rutine => {
    rutine.type = getValueOfFirstProperty(rutine)
    return rutine
  })
)
```

And lets try some OOP approach

```js
const myDailyRutine = [{
    createdLetter: {
      date: "2018-10-12T05:44:44.553216+00:00",
      user: {
        username: "lady-gaga"
      },
    },
  },
  {
    commentedEmail: {
      date: "2018-10-12T05:44:44.553216+00:00",
      user: {
        username: "la-gaga",
        display_name: "La Gaga"
      },
    },
  },
  {
    commentedEmail: {
      date: "2018-10-12T05:44:44.553216+00:00",
      user: {
        username: "maira-ter",
        display_name: "Ma Ter"
      },
    },
  },
]

class Rutine {
  constructor(type, rutine) {
    this.type = type // not necessary as we have got instance of CommentedEmail or CreatedLetter
    Object.keys(rutine[type]).forEach(key => this[key] = rutine[type][key])
  }
}

class CommentedEmail extends Rutine {
  constructor(rutine) {
    super('commentedEmail', rutine)
  }
}

class CreatedLetter extends Rutine {
  constructor(rutine) {
    super('createdLetter', rutine)
  }
}

const rutine = rutine => {
  switch (Object.keys(rutine)[0]) {
    case 'commentedEmail':
      return new CommentedEmail(rutine)
    case 'createdLetter':
      return new CreatedLetter(rutine)
  }
}

console.log(
  myDailyRutine.map(rutine)
)
```